# Not getting full result when output is on one line

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

Im new at Prolog , and I am  trying some manipulation on graphs .

I have a problem in my implementation, and since it is very long and complicated to expose , I will give a simple and similar problem .

Let say we have the following graph :

```
edge(a,e).
edge(e,d).
edge(d,c).
edge(c,b).
edge(b,a).
edge(d,a).
edge(e,c).
edge(f,b).
```

And I wanted to make this graph bidirected . I use the following code :

```
graph(Graph):-findall(A-B, edge(A,B), L),
    findall(B-A, edge(A,B), L1),
    append(L, L1, Graph).
```

when executing the query I get this result :

```
?- graph(Graph).
Graph = [a-e, b-a, c-b, d-a, d-c, e-c, e-d, f-b, ... - ...|...].
```

My problem is not in the code my problem is in the results as you can see I don't get the complete results, its always giving me only 8 edges and the rest are not shown.

How to solve this ?

Comment: If you hit <kbd>w</kdbd>, it will write the full list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not in SWI-Prolog, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JimAshworth: if you write `graph(G);true.` then the program will pause after the first statement. Next you can hit W and it will again write the answer but now in full.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah, so only useful while the query is still 'active' - good to know, thanks for that.

Comment: @ WillemVanOnsem thank's

Comment: See [Help: I want the whole answer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
graph(Graph),writeln(Graph).
```

`writeln/1` writes out the entire variable to the output.

From @WillemVanOnsem

If you write `graph(G);true.` then the program will pause after the first statement. Next you can hit <kbd>W</kbd> and it will again write the answer but now in full.

Comment: ` ?- graph(Graph),writeln(Graph).`
`[a-e,b-a,c-b,d-a,d-c,e-c,e-d,f-b,a-b,a-d,b-c,b-f,c-d,c-e,d-e,e-a]` 
`Graph = [a-e, b-a, c-b, d-a, d-c, e-c, e-d, f-b, ... - ...|...]. `

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: yes problem solved .... I just want to ask this , is there any way to get or to trnsform the results from prolog into a graphic representation (get the nodes and the connexions edges ) ?

Comment: @StambouliA.ouadoud That would be a new question, but I think there is? Ask a new question and someone will know.